# Transmon: why do we need unharmonic hamiltonian to isolate energy levels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian

With a quantum harmonic oscillator, we cannot isolate energy levels, e.g. to create a qubit. We need to embed anharmonicity, to get unevenly-spaced energy levels and so making them *distinguishable*.

This last word makes my doubt. It escapes me why this is true.

Comment: Yes. As you said there: "The main point is that your other states should be out-of-resonance when you 'talk to the qubit'. The role of the anharmonicity is to detune the other levels of the harmonic oscillator out of resonance." Thank you.

Comment: However, I would like to delve into the meaning of the above quote: what does happen if higher states are not out-of-resonance?

Comment: Then you don't have a qubit, but a more complex system. E.g., when you manipulate the qubit, your particle may exvite to a level that is not part of the qubit.